# Extract the missing row by comparing two table

Tags: sql

e.g.

**Simplified Case Tables:**

[image: Table A which contain the missing row entry in table B]

```
select count(1) from table_a; --> returns 5 results
select count(1) from table_b; --> returns 4 results
select count(1) from table_a, table_b2 b 
where b.id_ab like a.id_ab; --> returns 4 results
select count(1) from table_a, table_b2 b 
where b.id_ab not like a.id_ab; --> returns unexpected result
```

**SQL:**

tried this (except) but encountered error.

```
select a.id_ab from table_a a, table_b b except select a.id_ab from table_a, table_b2 b 
where b.id_ab not like a.id_ab;
```

or how to use union to do it? e.g.

```
(Select * from table_a except select * from table_b) Union All (Select * from table_b     except select record_id from table_a);
```

Expected Result:

[image: results]

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select a.id_ab 
from table_a a 
    LEFT JOIN table_b b on a.id_ab = b.id_ab 
where b.id_ab is null
```

Comment: Thanks legendofawesomeness. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Use below query (added left outer join) .

It will get data which is not matched in table_a .

```
 select count(1) from table_a, table_b2 b 
 where b.id_ab(+) = a.id_ab;
```

If u want only missing row use below query

```
 select count(1) from table_a, table_b2 b 
 where b.id_ab <> a.id_ab;
```

If you use UNION between queries  columns should be equal .

Example

```
   SELECT col1,col2 from table_a
   UNION
   SELECT col1,col2 from table_b
```

But not like

```
  SELECT col1,col2 from table_a
   UNION
   SELECT col1 from table_b
```